# In a file foo, how do you locate and print all lines containing printf, but not sprintf and fprintf, anywhere but at the end of a line using grep?

Tags: unix, grep, pipe

I am fairly new to Unix and am trying to conquer this problem exercise. I am using the grep command to get this task done and I know I will have to use piping, but I'm missing something. So far I was able to use grep to exclude any line with sprintf and fprintf, however it shouldn't print out a line that has printf as the end of the sentence and I am not quite sure what I am missing to get that done. I will post my work in the terminal below as reference.

Here is the file I am reading from:

```
 ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/assignments/a7 (cs3300-301722)$ cat foo.txt
 You should not pay attention to printf
 sprintf would be cool but we dont need it
 I think the printf command is fun
 fprintf is not needed either
 printf acceptable in this case
 printf sprintf fprintf printf sprintf printf
 What does sprintf printf and fprintf mean
 In order to get printf I need to use grep
 goodbye
```

Here is my command and my output:

```
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/assignments/a7 (cs3300-301722)$ grep 'printf' 
foo.txt | grep -v 'sprintf' | grep -v 'fprintf'
You should not pay attention to printf
I think the printf command is fun
printf acceptable in this case
In order to get printf I need to use grep
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data (or edit the above for better readability) with the expected output. Don't post them as comments or images. Thanks.  Not my downvote, btw

Comment: Thank you, Im not a regular user here and did not notice the formatting issues.

Comment: You want all lines with `printf` in them except when the `printf` is at the end? Try `grep -v "printf$"`. The `$` means "end of line" so it will exclude all printf's at the end of the line.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much !